# how to get the TimePickerDialog AM PM values

Tags: android, timepicker

I want to get the AM/PM values through the timePickerDialog. my code is such, it is taking input through user via timepickerdialog and set the alarm. here I am getting user input

```
datetime = Calendar.getInstance();
new TimePickerDialog(this,this,datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR),datetime.get(Calendar.MINUTE),false).show();
```

now when the onTimeSet function call i can get the user selected hour and minutes but not able to get the AM/PM value that user selected. here is other code

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) { try { Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
String am_pm;

if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
    am_pm = "AM";
else if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM)
    am_pm = "PM";

time.set(Calendar.HOUR, hourOfDay);
time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
//time.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
//time.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
//time.set(Calendar.AM_PM,datetime.PM);

AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);      
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_long);
```

Comment: @Philipp Reichart thanks for the reply. i got the understanding from the below post . now i am not talking abt AM PM values. i got the ans that android convert it to 24 hour format when user select. but after setting the Hour_Of_Day and minutes parameters of my "time" object (above code). i call the set method and call the time.getTimeInMillis(). but problem is that when i set the time for the next day (say my current system time is 9:00 pm and i set 8:00 pm that is of next day) but alarmManager trigger the alarm immediately. can u guide me regarding this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this answers your question.

[TimePickerDialog and AM or PM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2660148/1089811)

Comment: No, i am unable to get the AM/PM field. My system is showing 11:00 PM time when i set the alarm via timepicerdialog at 11:05 AM then alarm invoke at 11:05 PM instead of AM

Answer (score 10):

Create a new instance of the calendar within your listener, as like follows

```
Calendar datetime = Calendar.getInstance();
     c.set(Calendar.HOUR, mHour);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);

    if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
        am_pm = "AM";
    else if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM) {
        am_pm = "PM";
         if (hourOfDay > 12)
              hourOfDay = hourOfDay - 12;
    }
```

**Updated:**

```
Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

 mHour = mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
 mMinute = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


 TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(mActivity, mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);

 private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
     public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

         mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
         mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
         SimpleDateFormat mSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
         String time = mSDF.format(mCalendar.getTime());
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks it saves my day

Comment: @Jayabal Thanks. Here is the Kotlin version. val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
        val mSDF = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a")
        val time = mSDF.format(calendar.getTime())

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    String am_pm = "";

    Calendar datetime = Calendar.getInstance();
    datetime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    datetime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

    if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
        am_pm = "AM";
    else if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM)
        am_pm = "PM";

    String strHrsToShow = (datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR) == 0) ?"12":datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR)+""; 

    ((Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnEventStartTime)).setText( strHrsToShow+":"+datetime.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+" "+am_pm );
}
```