# How to set the TimePickerDialog to 24 hour?

Tags: android, timepicker, custom-datetimepicker

I know how to set the TimePicker widget to 24 hour, how do you do the same for the TimePickerDialog???

Otherwise will I have to make a new dialog box altogether??

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659954/timepickerdialog-and-am-or-pm

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Basically there is a constructor parameter

public TimePickerDialog (Context context, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener callBack, int hourOfDay, int minute, `boolean is24HourView`)

and this link might also help you

[TimePickerDialog and AM or PM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659954/timepickerdialog-and-am-or-pm)

---

Cheers

Comment: thanks man, that works perfectly. Secondly how do I modify the  TimePickerDialog, I want to remove the time listed at the top.

Comment: mark it as an answer please and ask another question with examples of what you tried to do and what exactly you want to have. be as more specific as possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Show a timepicker when the timeButton is clicked**

```
    timeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            TimePickerDialog tpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
                    CreateBookingActivity.this,
                    now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                    now.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                    true
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
edit_event_time.setClickable(true);
    edit_event_time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
            String time = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
            Log.e("time", "time " + sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
            String inputTime = time, inputHours, inputMinutes;

            inputHours = inputTime.substring(0, 2);
            inputMinutes = inputTime.substring(3, 5);

            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(DashBoardActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {

                    if (selectedHour == 0) {
                        selectedHour += 12;
                        timeFormat = "AM";
                    } else if (selectedHour == 12) {
                        timeFormat = "PM";
                    } else if (selectedHour > 12) {
                        selectedHour -= 12;
                        timeFormat = "PM";
                    } else {
                        timeFormat = "AM";
                    }

                    String selectedTime = selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute + " " + timeFormat;

                    edit_event_time.setText(selectedTime);

                }
            }, Integer.parseInt(inputHours), Integer.parseInt(inputMinutes), true);//mention true for 24 hour's time format,false for 12 hour's time format
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
            mTimePicker.show();
        }
    });
```