# How do I set AM/PM in a TimePicker?

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I am using a TimePicker in my app. Whenever the user opens the screen with the TimePicker, I initialize it with the current time. When I do this, the TimePicker shows AM instead of PM. Why does this happen? Is there anything I have to add in my code?

```
Date initDate = m_NoteManageObject.getDateTimeArray(position);
Calendar myCal = Calendar.getInstance();

myCal.setTime(initDate);
TimePicker timePicker  = (TimePicker)layout.findViewById(R.id.time_picker);

// Initialise Time Picker

timePicker.setCurrentHour(myCal.get(Calendar.HOUR));
timePicker.setCurrentMinute(myCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

Comment: I had the same issue and I have figured it out. If you use Calendar.HOUR, it means you are ignoring value of AM/PM. Instead, while setting current hour, use Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY to take AM/PM into consideration.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You'll have to use `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` instead of `Calendar.HOUR`.

i.e., `timePicker.setCurrentHour()` always expects the argument in 24-hour format. Unfortunately, this fact is not documented properly in the API documentation.

Comment: I set the time in `textView` and use same textView to pick time. When I set time with `timePicker`, it becomes visible to textView but when I select textView **again** to pick time, `timePicker` sets `AM/PM` to **AM**. Please give a solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePickerDialog view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    if(hourOfDay>=0 && hourOfDay<12){
        time = hourOfDay + " : " + minute + " AM";
    } else {
        if(hourOfDay == 12){
            time = hourOfDay + " : " + minute + "PM";
        } else{
            hourOfDay = hourOfDay -12;
            time = hourOfDay + " : " + minute + "PM";
        }
    }

    deliveryTime.setText(time);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to override the onTimeSet() method of the Timepicker. Check this link

[TimePickerDialog and AM or PM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659954/timepickerdialog-and-am-or-pm)

May it helps you..

Comment: I am not using a TimePickerDialog, I simple use the TimePicker widget i my xml layout.

Comment: But in the settings, is it in 24 Hours format?? Just check it and try using 12 hours format.

Comment: No its in 12 hour format..actually in the timepicker i want to show am or pm depending on current time

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-time-picker-example/                    try with this..

Answer (score 1):

First, get an instance of the `Calendar` class, then use `HOUR_OF_DAY` to get the hour. `HOUR_OF_DAY` will be in 24-hour format so just assign that to a variable and then check whether that int is greater than `0` and less than `12`. If this condition is true then append `AM` or else `PM`. Because `HOUR_OF_DAY` is 24-hour format, the PM hours will be displayed as `13,14` so to handle this, just subtract the `HOUR_OF_DAY` by `12`. Here is the code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
if (hour < 12 && hour >= 0) {
    tv.setText(hour + " AM");
} else {
    hour -= 12;
    if(hour == 0) {
        hour = 12;
    }
    tv.setText(hour + " PM");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(0, 0, 0, hourOfDay, minute, 0);
            long timeInMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
            java.text.DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
            Date date = new Date();
            date.setTime(timeInMillis);
            time.setText(dateFormatter.format(date));
```