# TimePicker - how to set AM or PM?

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I am new to android ,In my app I have a timepicker here I need to programmatically set the hour,minute,AM/PM values .

The value of the time is "11:11:AM" ,In this I have set the hour and time and it is working fine .but I don't know how to set the AM/PM values .

code:

```
  if (!(mTime == null)) {
                String timme = mTime;
                String[] time = timme.split(":");
                int hour = Integer.parseInt(time[0].trim());
                int min = Integer.parseInt(time[1].trim());
                String amPm = ((time[2].trim()));

                mTimePicker.setIs24HourView(false);
                mTimePicker.setHour(hour);
                mTimePicker.setMinute(min);
            }
```

Image:

[image]

It always shows "AM" even if the string has "PM".
Can anyone help me to fix this .

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381985/how-do-i-set-am-pm-in-a-timepicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android automatically sets AM/PM based on time it is supplied in 24 hours format. To clarify:

You have to set TimePicker to 12 hour mode by calling

```
yourtimepicker.setIs24HourView(false)
```

and then supply time in 24 hour format using

```
yourtimepicker.setHour(22)
```

If i were you i would take string apart and check if last part was AM or PM and if it is PM i would add 12 to hour value, so if it was `11:11:PM` i would get 23 hours, give it to android and let it take care of everything else.

NOTE: this works for both spinner and clock mode

Comment: Perfect Answer!!!. TimePicker can only accept 24 hour format time.  and .setIs24HourView(false) method will convert the format and show am/pm layout.

Answer (score 1):

call like this ,

```
mTimePicker.setIs24HourView(false);
```

[Learn more here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker)

Comment: @Zhu can u share ur screen

Comment: I have updated the image and It always shows AM even if the string has PM @GobuCSG

Comment: hey dude, just u pass 24 hrs format it will make it 12 hrs format that's all.

Answer (score 0):

The  `String = aTime` is a `24 hour` formatted string

```
   mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(context, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                    String timeSet;
                    if (selectedHour > 12) {
                        selectedHour -= 12;
                        timeSet = "PM";
                    } else if (selectedHour == 0) {
                        selectedHour += 12;
                        timeSet = "AM";
                    } else if (selectedHour == 12)
                        timeSet = "PM";
                    else
                        timeSet = "AM";
                    String minutes = "";
                    if (selectedMinute < 10)
                        minutes = "0" + selectedMinute;
                    else
                        minutes = String.valueOf(selectedMinute);

                    String aTime = new StringBuilder().append(selectedHour).append(':')
                            .append(minutes).append(" ").append(timeSet).toString();

                    relatedWorkTime.setText(aTime);

                }
            }, hour, minute, false);
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
            mTimePicker.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below Code to add convert from 24-hour format to 12-hour format and add AM/PM.

```
String time =  ((hourOfDay > 12) ? hourOfDay % 12 : hourOfDay) + ":" + (minute < 10 ? ("0" + minute) : minute) + " " + ((hourOfDay >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM");
```

Please find the entire code of android timepicker below.

---

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                // Launch Time Picker Dialog
                TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(CreateNewBatchActivity.this,
                        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                                  int minute) {
                                String time =  ((hourOfDay > 12) ? hourOfDay % 12 : hourOfDay) + ":" + (minute < 10 ? ("0" + minute) : minute) + " " + ((hourOfDay >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM");

                                buttonBatchStartTime.setText(time);
                            }
                        }, mHour, mMinute, false);
                timePickerDialog.show();
```