# Can we display Old Style Time picker (Pre Lollipop Time Picker ) in lollipop devices

Tags: android, android-timepicker, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I want to show older time picker (like pre lollipop devices time picker ) in lollipop devices. Can This is possible.

Comment: You can refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516389/android-timepickerdialog-set-max-time/48861375#48861375

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can specify the spinner-style time picker by setting the timePickerMode attribute to "spinner". The default value on Material is "clock".

Comment: Can you guide me how to pragmatically set to time picker dialog. Or should I use this from xml ?

Comment: u have to use xml and add the line to its xml tag... <TimePicker
    ...
    android:timePickerMode="spinner" />