# Timepicker alert dialog, restrict visibility into new time format in higher version

Tags: android, timepicker

I have a TimePicker which looks like spinner in higher versions of devices looks like clock, I want to restrict the view not to change in higher version, which should look like spinner only.. can anyone please help me to solve this?

Comment: yes you can do that check this links.. which will help you.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277683/datapicker-looks-like-old-design-on-new-apis-as-well?lq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773646/can-we-display-old-style-time-picker-pre-lollipop-time-picker-in-lollipop-dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself by taking an alert dialog and custom xml view on that alert with timepicker, calling the alert on click of the button, 
Solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want your timePicker look the same to all versions of android, you need use library

[https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers'](https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers)

Comment: Thats very usefull thanx bro (y)