# How to set min time and max time using timepicker dialogFragment android

Tags: java, timepicker

I want to restrict the range of time in timepicker. For that, I need to set minimum and maximum time in TimePickerDialog Fragment. I have searched many sites for this simple issue, but i didn't any get proper solution. I am getting the solution only for datepicker and number picker. Any help would be appreciate.

and I have used the below code:

```
    public class TimePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String TIME_IN_MILLIS = "com.iandmydoctor.android.utils.TIME_IN_MILLIS";

    private OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetCallback;
    private boolean is24HourView = false;

    public TimePickerDialogFragment() {
    }

    public void setOnTimeSetListener(OnTimeSetListener listener) {
        mTimeSetCallback = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle b = getArguments();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        long time = b.getLong(TIME_IN_MILLIS);

        if (time < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        c.setTimeInMillis(time);
        int mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            boolean fired = false;

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                if (fired) {
                    return;
                }
                fired = true;
                if (mTimeSetCallback != null) {
                    mTimeSetCallback.onTimeSet(hourOfDay, minute);
                }
            }
        };


        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, mHour, mMinute, is24HourView);
    }



    public void setIs24HourView(boolean is24HourView) {
        this.is24HourView = is24HourView;
    }

    public interface OnTimeSetListener {
        void onTimeSet(int hourOfDay, int minute);
    }

}
```

and in my activity:

```
  private void showTimePickerDialog(long timeInMillis, TimePickerDialogFragment.OnTimeSetListener listener) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putLong(TimePickerDialogFragment.TIME_IN_MILLIS, timeInMillis);
    TimePickerDialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerDialogFragment();
    timePicker.setArguments(args);
    timePicker.setOnTimeSetListener(listener);
    timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "time_picker");
}
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516389/android-timepickerdialog-set-max-time

Comment: Thank you..Shinil...working nice.

Comment: Happy to help you :)