# Android - Set minimum and maximum time for Time picker

Tags: android, time, android-timepicker

I am trying to set the min and max time for time picker. I am giving the values like following

**1 -> min - 10:00 and max - 12:00**

**2 -> min - 15:00 and max - 18:00**

**3 -> min - 19:00 max 20:00**

**4 -> min - 23:00 max 24:00**

And I am using the following code:

```
@Override
    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                boolean flag = true;

                if (hourOfDay <= maximumHour && hourOfDay >= minimumHour) {
                    if (hourOfDay == maximumHour && hourOfDay == minimumHour) {
                        if (minute > maximumMin)
                            flag = false;
                        else if (minute < minimumMin)
                            flag = false;
                        else if (minute == maximumMin && minute == minimumMin) {
                            flag = false;
                        } else if (minute == maximumMin) {
                            flag = false;
                        } else if (minute == minimumMin) {
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    } else if (hourOfDay == maximumHour) {
                        if (minute > maximumMin) {
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    } else if (hourOfDay == minimumHour) {
                        if (minute < minimumMin)
                            flag = false;
                    }
                    if (flag) {
                        curHour = hourOfDay;
                        curMin = minute;
                    } else {
                        updateTime(curHour, curMin);

                    }
                }
}
```

This code is working for 2nd and 3rd scenarios. But for 1st and 4th scenarios I can not set the time to 12 AM or 12 PM. I can set upto 11:59 AM and 11:59 PM.

I verified [Android TimePickerDialog set max time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516389/android-timepickerdialog-set-max-time) this too. But I am getting same issue. please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

try     datePicker.setMaxDate();
datePicker.setMinDate();

please check this link as well : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253379/datepicker-and-timepicker-set-max-and-min-values)

Comment: Right now I can not change the TimePickerDialog.