# Android: Different appearience on UI of date and time picker

Tags: android, android-datepicker, android-timepicker, daterangepicker

I am using date and time picker in my application and referred the tutorial
from [here](http://moorandroid.blogspot.in/p/date-time-picker-views.html) but the problem is that when i run it on kitkat 4.2.2 it show output as follows:[image] but when i run it on lollipop 5.1.1 it shows output [image]

showing two different UI on same code i dont know how to fix this problem.I have also applied some validations on it but its working with first case but not with second case.Please help.

Comment: Is that really a problem? It adapts to the UI style normally used on the device.

Comment: @Henry yeah but in second UI Style it is not considering any validations applied by me

Comment: you can try to use different UI libraries for date pickers if you want

Answer (score 4):

if you want it identical to the first one you can add

```
android:datePickerMode="spinner" 
android:calendarViewShown="false"
```

Comment: is that same applied to timepicker as well?

Answer (score 3):

This differs as per OS version in devices. **It is a system date and time picker**.

So it will be as per OS version and **may - may not differ in each of the OS version**.

Whatever you are seeing is correct and is OS level change.

Comment: but how to deal with validations with second screen because in my case validations not working for second approch

Comment: all validations i applied like date should not be less than todays date and time picker user can not select time less than current time for todays date

Comment: according to me it should work in both cases, in my app its working for all devices with different OS versions @Dhiraj OR show code

Comment: or else user can select time between 6AM-10PM For other dates for validation purpose on time picker i have used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516389/android-timepickerdialog-set-max-time this for reference

Comment: from this link, it should be working if you haved used it @Dhiraj

Comment: its working for datepicker validation but not for time picker validation

Comment: i am trying to work it but if it fails i will tell you

Comment: @ Amit Vaghela ok just trying

Answer (score 0):

I think you can force it to look a certain way by changing compilessdkversion and the targetsdkversion accordingly in your gradle file.

edit: on second thought, I'm not 100% sure it'll work...might cause problems on some versions. 
The 100% positive way to get the classic spinner is like Maxi said to set the attribute datepickermode atribute to spinner. 
To answer whats been asked of Maxi regarding timePicker. You have to set the timePickerMode attribute to "spinner" in a similar fashion to avoid the round clock interface and get the classic spinner.

```
<TimePicker
    ...
     android:timePickerMode="spinner" />
```