# How to set Maximum time and Minimum time in timepicker widget on android

Tags: android

I found solutions for how to set max and min time in time picker dialog. But, I am searching a solution for time picker widget in android(time picker declared in xml). Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you want to do that in xml??

Comment: @Charuka yes I want to do in xml.

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way using xml

Comment: @Charuka okay. thanks  for your kind response

Comment: Hey but if you want you can create your own class extends DatePickerDialog and do that :)

Comment: @Charuka okay thank you. I will try with number picker.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516389/android-timepickerdialog-set-max-time

Comment: See this stackoverflow link [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516389/android-timepickerdialog-set-max-time)