# android: TimePickerDialog prevent user select past time and can select future time with new date

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-timepicker

I am using this link [Android TimePickerDialog set max time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516389/android-timepickerdialog-set-max-time/16942630#16942630).

I am new in android. With the help of this code, I cannot select past time but we cannot select future time. When  12 is selected in timepickerdialog mode change to am automatically according to the next day not past day.

Comment: I am new in android. I am working on this task.

Comment: First read this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In current situation it is completely unclear what you want to accomplish and what is your problem. So first edit your question according to the link and make it more clear and precise

Comment: @VivekMishra He asked and this question is normal question. The main problem that TimePicker in  TimePickerDialog don't change current hour and minutes after onTimeChanged.

Comment: @AtifAmin so u want to disable all past time form timepicker?

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 yes , but they can select future time with new date??

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try this code:

```
TimePickerFragment timePickerFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
            timePickerFragment.setOnTimeSetListener(new OnTimeSetListener() {
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    Calendar datetime = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    datetime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                    datetime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                    if (datetime.getTimeInMillis() >= c.getTimeInMillis()) {
                        //it's after current
                         int hour = hourOfDay % 12;
                    btnPickStartTime.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d %s", hour == 0 ? 12 : hour,
                            minute, hourOfDay < 12 ? "am" : "pm"));
                    } else {
                        //it's before current'
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            timePickerFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TIME");
```

it will show the `timepicker` dialog and if user select any time before current time... it will show invalid time..

**EDIT**
You need to import:

```
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
```

Here is a Good [Example](https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2015/04/timepickerdialog-in-android.html)

Comment: what is time picker fragment here , where is the code snippet @rafsanahmad007

Comment: @Jeyaseelan i have edited the answer to include the import statements

Comment: thanks a lot @rafsanahmad007, but i have done it another way

Answer (score 7):

The best solution for you will be to use [this](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) material design library to pick time or date and set min value.

```
    TimePickerDialog tpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePickerDialog view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {
                //put some interesting code
            }
        },
        now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
        now.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
        true
    );
    tpd.setMinTime(10, 0, 0); // MIN: hours, minute, secconds
    tpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "TimePickerDialog");
```

> The easiest way to add the Material DateTime Picker library to your project is by adding it as a dependency to your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.0.0'
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
private int  mHour, mMinute;
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

// Launch Time Picker Dialog
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(ActivityScheduleTransfer.this,
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                final Calendar checkOldDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                  if (hourOfDay >= checkOldDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) { 
                      if (hourOfDay == checkOldDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) && minute <= checkOldDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) {
                                return;
                        }
                    //select current after 
                } else {`enter code here`
                    //select current before 
                }
            }
        }, mHour, mMinute, false);
            timePickerDialog.show();
```