# I want to restrict future time in timepicker dilog

Tags: android

Here is my code i want to restrict future time in timepicker dilog.

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {


        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minutes) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            hour = hourOfDay;
            minute = minutes;

            updateTime(hour, minute);

        }

    };

    private static String utilTime(int value) {

        if (value < 10)
            return "0" + String.valueOf(value);
        else
            return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    // Used to convert 24hr format to 12hr format with AM/PM values
    private void updateTime(int hours, int mins) {

        String timeSet = "";
        if (hours > 12) {
            hours -= 12;
            timeSet = "PM";
        } else if (hours == 0) {
            hours += 12;
            timeSet = "AM";
        } else if (hours == 12)
            timeSet = "PM";
        else
            timeSet = "AM";


        String minutes = "";
        if (mins < 10)
            minutes = "0" + mins;
        else
            minutes = String.valueOf(mins);

        // Append in a StringBuilder
        String aTime = new StringBuilder().append(hours).append(':')
                .append(minutes).append(" ").append(timeSet).toString();

        txttime.setText(aTime);

        SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = parseFormat.parse(aTime.toString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(parseFormat.format(date) + " = " + displayFormat.format(date));
        Log.e("date :", "date is " + displayFormat.format(date));

        timeconvert = displayFormat.format(date).toString();
        Log.e("timeconvert :", "time is " + timeconvert.toString());

    }**strong text**
```

Comment: you want only past date time and current date time ?

Comment: yes exactly ....

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516389/android-timepickerdialog-set-max-time

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for you will be to use [this](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) material design library to pick time or date and set min value.

```
 TimePickerDialog tpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onTimeSet(TimePickerDialog view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {
                //put some interesting code 
            } 
        }, 
        now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
        now.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
        true 
    ); 
       Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        Timepoint mTimepoint = new Timepoint( now.get(Calendar.HOUR),now.get(Calendar.MINUTE),now.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        tpd.setMaxTime(mTimepoint);
    tpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "TimePickerDialog");
```

> The easiest way to add the Material DateTime Picker library to your project is by adding it as a dependency to your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

 timePickerDialog.setMaxTime(now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), now.get(Calendar.MINUTE),now.get(Calendar.SECOND));}
```