# Min time for Timepicker dialog

Tags: android, timepicker

How to set min time on timepicker dialog or disable past time on timepicker dialog in android.
Any library suggestion ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android TimePickerDialog set max time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516389/android-timepickerdialog-set-max-time)

Comment: And read [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16942630/4168607).

Comment: Check this library : https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

Comment: @ADM but how I can disable not selectable time(Hour) ?

Comment: @MaheshVayak On this how I can set min date to TimePicker

Comment: @NiteshShrivas see below code

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener
```

**For Time Picker**

```
@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
public void showTimePicker(Calendar calendar) {
    Calendar minTimeCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    minTimeCalendar.setTime(localToGMT(minTimeCalendar.getTime()));
    TimePickerDialog tpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(this, calendar.get(11), calendar.get(12), true);
    if (compareToDate(calendar.getTime(), minTimeCalendar.getTime())) {
        minTimeCalendar.add(12, 60);
        tpd.setMinTime(minTimeCalendar.get(11), 0, 0);
    }

    **tpd.enableMinutes(false);**
    tpd.setVersion(TimePickerDialog.Version.VERSION_2);
    tpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "TimePickDialog");
}
```

**For Date Picker**

```
 public void showDatePicker(Calendar calendar) {
    Calendar minDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (currentHour == 24) {
        minDateCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    }
    minDateCalendar.setTime(localToGMT(minDateCalendar.getTime()));
    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(this, calendar.get(1), calendar.get(2), calendar.get(5));

    dpd.setMinDate(minDateCalendar);
    dpd.setVersion(DatePickerDialog.Version.VERSION_2);
    dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePickerDialog");
}
```

**Both Override method**

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
     //display selected date here code
}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePickerDialog view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {
    //display selected time here code
}
```

Hope this helps you...if you need any help you can ask

Comment: @Nitesh Shrivas You can enable and disable minutes and set min time easy