# Changing time picker to 12 hour format

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a time picker application that is showing 24 hour format after picking the time. How do I change it to 12 hour format? I have a sample code shown below, can anyone help me out with this? thanks

java code

```
package com.botskool.TimePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TimePickerActivity extends Activity {
    /** Private members of the class */
    private TextView displayTime;
    private Button pickTime;

    private int pHour;
    private int pMinute;
    /** This integer will uniquely define the dialog to be used for displaying time picker.*/
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    /** Callback received when the user "picks" a time in the dialog */
    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                pHour = hourOfDay;
                pMinute = minute;
                updateDisplay();
                displayToast();
            }
        };

    /** Updates the time in the TextView */
    private void updateDisplay() {
        displayTime.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    .append(pad(pHour)).append(":")
                    .append(pad(pMinute)));
    }

    /** Displays a notification when the time is updated */
    private void displayToast() {
        Toast.makeText(this, new StringBuilder().append("Time choosen is ").append(displayTime.getText()),   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    /** Add padding to numbers less than ten */
    private static String pad(int c) {
        if (c >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(c);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_time_picker);

        /** Capture our View elements */
        displayTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeDisplay);
        pickTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickTime);

        /** Listener for click event of the button */
        pickTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

        /** Get the current time */
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        pHour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        pMinute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        /** Display the current time in the TextView */
        updateDisplay();
    }

    /** Create a new dialog for time picker */

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    mTimeSetListener, pHour, pMinute, false);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

xml code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/timeDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Time will appear here after being selected"
    android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/pickTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change the time"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659954/timepickerdialog-and-am-or-pm

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat. Try This:

```
final String inputTime = "17:34";

try {
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm");
    final Date dateObj = sdf.parse(time);
    String outputTime = new SimpleDateFormat("K:mm a").format(dateObj);
} catch (final ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```