# How to know user has selected AM or PM in TimePicker dialog view

Tags: android

I want to pick whether user has selected AM or PM  in `TimePicker View`.Here is my `onTimeSet` method and I don't know what to put in place of the '?'.

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
c.set(Calendar.AM_PM, ?);

    }
```

Comment: Errk, never mind. Looked at the documentation. Does [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#AM_PM) help?

Comment: Check this answer: [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659954/timepickerdialog-and-am-or-pm/2660148#2660148) Basically (hourOfDay < 12) ? AM : PM