# How to set Time with the help of Timepicker? with 12 hour format

Tags: android, timepicker

I set the timepicker and it is working perfectly but the thing is that i want to set like **`5:00 AM`**  and i get the output 24 hours format but i want to set 12 hours format.

Here the code :-

```
    package com.example.sachin.timepicker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends  Activity {
    boolean isFromClicked = false;

    TextView tvDisplayTime, tvDisplayTime1;
    EditText btnChangeTime, btnChangeTime1, addtaskname, addtaskdetail;
    Button addtaskbtn;
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    String addtask, adddetail, addstart, addend;
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 999;
    private static String url_addevent = "http://10.0.2.2/portal/index.php";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnChangeTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeTime);
        btnChangeTime1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeTime1);
        addtaskname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addtaskname);
        addtaskdetail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addtaskdetail);

        addtaskbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addtaskbtn);
        addtaskbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                addtask = addtaskname.getText().toString();
                addstart = btnChangeTime.getText().toString();
                addend = btnChangeTime1.getText().toString();
                adddetail = addtaskdetail.getText().toString();

                if (addtask.equals(null) || addtask.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Add  Name !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (addstart.equals(null) || addstart.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Add Duty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (addend.equals(null) || addend.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please  Add Number!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (adddetail.equals(null) || adddetail.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please  Add Number!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {

                    securityUser();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Event Added Successfully. !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });


        setCurrentTimeOnView();
        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    private void securityUser() {
        daily_task(addtask, addstart, addend, adddetail);
    }

    private void daily_task(String addtask, String addstart, String addend, String adddetail) {

        class eventUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            RegisterUserClass ruc = new RegisterUserClass();

            //@Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // Create a progressdialog
                super.onPreExecute();
//                loading = ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(), "Please Wait...!!!", null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();

                param.put("dt_tname", params[0]);
                param.put("dt_stime", params[1]);
                param.put("dt_etime", params[2]);
                param.put("dt_detail", params[3]);

                String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(url_addevent, param);
                Log.d("Result", result);
                Log.d("Data", param.toString());
                return result;
            }

            //@Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

              //  loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Security Added Successfully...!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      /*  Intent i1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i1);*/
            }
        }

        eventUser regi = new eventUser();
        regi.execute(addtask, addstart, addend, adddetail);
    }


    // display current time
   public void setCurrentTimeOnView() {

        btnChangeTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeTime);
        btnChangeTime1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeTime1);
        //  timePicker1 = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // set current time into textview
       btnChangeTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour)).append(":")
                .append(pad(minute)));
       btnChangeTime1.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour)).append(":")
                .append(pad(minute)));

        // set current time into timepicker
        //timePicker1.setCurrentHour(hour);
        //timePicker1.setCurrentMinute(minute);

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        btnChangeTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeTime);
        btnChangeTime1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeTime1);

        btnChangeTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
                isFromClicked = false;


            }

        });


        btnChangeTime1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
                isFromClicked = true;


            }

        });

    }


    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
                // set time picker as current time
                return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute,
                        false);

        }
        return null;
    }

    }
    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
                              int selectedMinute) {
            hour = selectedHour;
            minute = selectedMinute;

            // set current time into textview
            if ( isFromClicked )
                btnChangeTime1.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour))
                        .append(":").append(pad(minute)));
            else
                btnChangeTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour))
                        .append(":").append(pad(minute)));
            // set current time into timepicker
         //   timePicker1.setCurrentHour(hour);
           // timePicker1.setCurrentMinute(minute);

        }
    };

    private static String pad(int c) {
        if (c >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(c);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
    }
}
```

the above code is my complete code please help me with the same code

Comment: May be this link can help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659954/timepickerdialog-and-am-or-pm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the below conversion

```
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
     int hour = hourOfDay % 12;
     if (hour == 0) hour = 12;
     String _AM_PM = (hourOfDay > 12) ? "PM" : "AM";
     System.out.println(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d %s", hour, minute, _AM_PM));
}
```

this overidden function is called when you select the time from the **TimePickerDialog**.

**Full ANSWER**

```
    package com.example.sachin.timepicker;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.TimePicker;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Locale;

    public class MainActivity extends  Activity {
        boolean isFromClicked = false;

        TextView tvDisplayTime, tvDisplayTime1;
        EditText btnChangeTime, btnChangeTime1, addtaskname, addtaskdetail;
        Button addtaskbtn;
        private int hour;
        private int minute;
        String addtask, adddetail, addstart, addend;
        static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 999;
        private static String url_addevent = "http://10.0.2.2/portal/index.php";

        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnChangeTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeTime);
        btnChangeTime1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeTime1);
        addtaskname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addtaskname);
        addtaskdetail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addtaskdetail);

        addtaskbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addtaskbtn);
        addtaskbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                addtask = addtaskname.getText().toString();
                addstart = btnChangeTime.getText().toString();
                addend = btnChangeTime1.getText().toString();
                adddetail = addtaskdetail.getText().toString();

                if (addtask.equals(null) || addtask.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Add  Name !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (addstart.equals(null) || addstart.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Add Duty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (addend.equals(null) || addend.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please  Add Number!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (adddetail.equals(null) || adddetail.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please  Add Number!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    securityUser();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Event Added Successfully. !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        setCurrentTimeOnView();
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    private void securityUser() {
        daily_task(addtask, addstart, addend, adddetail);
    }

    private void daily_task(String addtask, String addstart, String addend, String adddetail) {

        class eventUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            RegisterUserClass ruc = new RegisterUserClass();

            //@Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // Create a progressdialog
                super.onPreExecute();
//                loading = ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(), "Please Wait...!!!", null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();

                param.put("dt_tname", params[0]);
                param.put("dt_stime", params[1]);
                param.put("dt_etime", params[2]);
                param.put("dt_detail", params[3]);

                String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(url_addevent, param);
                Log.d("Result", result);
                Log.d("Data", param.toString());
                return result;
            }

            //@Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                //  loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Security Added Successfully...!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      /*  Intent i1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i1);*/
            }
        }

        eventUser regi = new eventUser();
        regi.execute(addtask, addstart, addend, adddetail);
    }


    // display current time
    public void setCurrentTimeOnView() {

        btnChangeTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeTime);
        btnChangeTime1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeTime1);
        //  timePicker1 = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // set current time into textview
        btnChangeTime.setText(getTimeText(hour, minute));
        btnChangeTime1.setText(getTimeText(hour, minute));

        // set current time into timepicker
        //timePicker1.setCurrentHour(hour);
        //timePicker1.setCurrentMinute(minute);

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        btnChangeTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeTime);
        btnChangeTime1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeTime1);

        btnChangeTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showTimePickerDialog();
                isFromClicked = false;
            }

        });

        btnChangeTime1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showTimePickerDialog();
                isFromClicked = true;
            }

        });
    }

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
                              int selectedMinute) {
            hour = selectedHour;
            minute = selectedMinute;
            // set current time into textview
            if (isFromClicked)
                btnChangeTime1.setText(getTimeText(hour, minute));
            else
                btnChangeTime.setText(getTimeText(hour, minute));
            // set current time into timepicker
            //   timePicker1.setCurrentHour(hour);
            // timePicker1.setCurrentMinute(minute);
        }
    };

    private void showTimePickerDialog() {
        new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute, true).show();
    }

    private String getTimeText(int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        int hour = hourOfDay % 12;
        if (hour == 0) hour = 12;
        String _AM_PM = (hourOfDay > 12) ? "PM" : "AM";
        return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d %s", hour, minute, _AM_PM);
    }
 }
```

Comment: yup its set to the 12 hour format.. thank you and if i want to set AM/PM then what thing i need to implement?

Comment: where you want to set Am/Pm

Comment: in DB as well as in EditText also

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
      Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
      hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
      minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
      SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
      formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
      System.out.println("Date : "+formattedDate);
```

Comment: what should i change? its the same code as i did but i didnt getting the output what i excatly wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SimpleDateFormat class to get the time in 12hour clock.

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.US);//First argument will be the format 
String timeFormat = sdf.format(/*Pass your time here*/);
```

So inside your onTimeSet() method just add the above lines.

Like,

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
                              int selectedMinute) {

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.US);//First argument will be the format 
String timeFormat = sdf.format(/*Pass your time here*/);
            btnChangeTime1.setText(timeFormat);

        }
```

Comment: i already get the time in 12 hour format but i wanted to display AM/PM in the EditText