# Time picker setText to 12hour format

Tags: android, timepicker

I have a time picker on a dialog that sets the EditText on what time its picked but whenever i select a time the format of the time is on military time.. How can I make it to 12hour format. Thaaanks :)

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
    if(id == DIALOG_ID){
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, dplistener, year_x,month_x,day_x);
    }

    else if (id == DIALOG_ID2){
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, tplistener, hour_x, minute_x, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(DetailActivity.this));
    }

    return null;
}


 protected TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener tplistener =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                hour_x = hourOfDay;
                minute_x = minute;
                etResTime.setText(hour_x +" : " + minute_x );
            }
        };
```

Comment: you can follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39762804/how-to-set-time-with-the-help-of-timepicker-with-12-hour-format/39763424#39763424

Comment: @Pihu - Thanks, just as what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

timePicker.setIs24HourView(false);

Answer (score 0):

```
protected TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener tplistener =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                int hour = hourOfDay % 12;
                if (hour == 0) hour = 12;
                String _AM_PM = (hourOfDay > 12) ? "PM" : "AM";
                etResTime.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d %s", hour, minute, _AM_PM));
            }
        };
```